# Delete Bitbucket LFS using Bitbucket Api

Tags: api, bitbucket, git-lfs

I'd like to delete a file on Bitbucket LFS providing its OID. I could not find on documentation how this can be done. this can be done? How?

Comment: did you checkout the documentation on bitbucket support for LFS https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-git-lfs-with-existing-bitbucket-repositories/

Comment: @simonarame I have checked. this link tell nothing about api usage

Answer (score 0):

The bitbucket API ( https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/ ) is not aimed at directly support standard GIT commands like receiving new commits, checkouts, push, etc )
The bitbucket api is rather exposed for what git as standard repositories does not cover out of the box like adding repositories, repositories metadata, pull requests approval, comments, workspaces, issues, pipelines, snippet and team management.

For dealing with standard git commands and GIT-LFS related commands, you could try to make use of standard libraries that gives programmatic access to GIT repositories like org.eclipse.jgit ( https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/ )
There is a few package that are specialized with git-lfs ( https://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/5.12.0.202106070339-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lfs/package-summary.html ) although deletion does not involve git-lfs specific commands as long we know the file path.

So you would typically carry the following in a pom.xml file or the alike :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
  <version>5.12.0.202106070339-r</version>
</dependency>
<dependency><!-- this second one is not used in the snippet below -->
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit.lfs</artifactId>
    <version>5.12.0.202106070339-r</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is an small code snippet in Java showing how you could proceed providing you can not only have the OID of the objects but are able to get the file paths as well.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.eclipse.jgit.api.CommitCommand;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.RmCommand;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.GitAPIException;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.NoFilepatternException;
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository;
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.RepositoryBuilder;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, NoFilepatternException, GitAPIException {
        
        File file = new File("c:/users/admin/git/MyRepo");
        Repository repo = new RepositoryBuilder().setWorkTree(file).build();
        
        Git git = new Git(repo);
        
        RmCommand rmc = new RmCommand(repo);
        rmc.addFilepattern("large_image_file.bmp");
        rmc.call();
        
        CommitCommand cc = git.commit();
        cc.setMessage("deleting large files");
        cc.call();
        
    }
}
```